# one field with different data types [SQLAlchemy]

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

I have a value that can be integer, float or string, and I created different columns:

```
#declarative
class MyClass(Base):

    #id and other Columns
    _value_str = Column(String(100))
    _value_int = Column(Integer)
    _value_float = Column(Float)

    def __init__(self,...,value):
        self._value_str = value if isinstance(value,(str,unicode)) else None
        self._value_int = value if isinstance(value,int) else None
        self._value_float = value if isinstance(value,float) else None
```

and i would like to do something like this:

```
>>> value = 'text'
>>> my_class = MyClass(value, ...)
>>> my_class.value
>>> 'text'
>>> session.add(my_class)
>>> session.commit()
#specialy this
>>> result = session.query(Myclass).filter(Myclass.value == 'text').one()
>>> print result.value 
>>> 'text'
```

Maybe i have a design problem, i accept any good idea

I'm newbe in SQLAlchemy

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a design problem - a bit of a mismatch between your DB and Python. In SQL variables (columns) have a type, whereas in python values have the type.

One possibility would be to use a single column (a string), but pickle the value before you store it.

This can be accomplished automatically with a [sqlalchemy custom type](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/types.html#custom-types).

Something along the lines of the following (uses [jsonpickle](http://jsonpickle.github.com/) to do the conversion rather than cpickle):

```
import sqlalchemy.types as types
import jsonpickle
from copy import deepcopy

class JsonType(types.MutableType, types.TypeDecorator):    
    impl = types.Unicode

    def process_bind_param(self, value, engine):
        return unicode(jsonpickle.encode(value))

    def process_result_value(self, value, engine):
        if value:
            rv = jsonpickle.decode(value)
            return rv
        else:
            return None

    def copy_value(self, value):
        return deepcopy(value)

    def compare_values(self, x, y):
        return x == y
```

And then use it as follows:

```
class MyClass(base):
    value = Column(JsonType())
```

Comment: grate!!, i was looking for something like that, but documentations is really bast, thank you

Comment: look, could interest you, this is an option ussing MapperExtention
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020394/sqlalchemy-how-to-map-against-a-read-only-or-calculated-property

Comment: Note with this answer that you can't use db functions e.g. sum()  on any floats or ints that you store.
The docs are actually quite good with SQLAlchemy - they have to cover a lot of ground - but yes, could do with at few more real world examples.