# SQLAlchemy/Jinja2 : Most efficient way to calculate DB aggregate data on the fly?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Following a question I asked about [storing in DB vs. calculating aggregate data on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086949/speed-store-aggregate-values-in-database-or-calculate-with-jinja) to display, here's another one on **how** to best serve this kind of data.

Please note we are talking about querying two different tables in the database, and some of the data to be displayed relies on multiple variables in one of the tables. The math operations aren't complicated, and include addition, multiplication, and division.

Right now the way I'm thinking of doing it, is in my `views.py`, querying both tables, and constructing a `dict` to then pass to my `index.html` via `views` and iterate using Jinja. I'm wondering whether this is acceptable, and what are some better ways to do it.

Comment: The obvious answer (to me) would be to calculate the aggregate using the database. Do you have a specific reason for not trying that instead?

Comment: @Wolph do you mean *storing* the aggregate data in the DB? I was advised otherwise. Perhaps my question isn't clear? I am in fact calculating them from the database, the question is how to serve them on the fly.

Comment: I mean joining the two tables in the database query instead of through jinja. Both are possible of course but I don't see why you would fetch 2 separate tables only to have jinja merge them together when a regular join should be able to do the same.

Comment: The reason is, I currently don't have any relationships set up between the two tables, although logically they are related. The need to re-work this database is becoming more apparent with time. Thank you.

Comment: Luckily sqlalchemy is pretty flexible so that shouldn't even be a problem. From your other question you could query it like this:
`sql.expression.label('calculation', (table_a.c.column_1 + table_a.c.column_2 + table_a.c.column_3 / table_a.c.column_6) * 100)`